# Is glob (using a unique prefix) faster than readdir?

Tags: c, posix, glob

There is a directory with many files and I need to open the file named like `00343dde41bac11ef7020935ee3d*`. I suspect that there is exactly one such file.

I know that accessing one file `fopen (3)` is faster than reading the entire directory `readdir (3)`.

Can it be assumed that using `glob (3)` will be significantly faster (require less disk access) than simply using `readdir (3)` and testing the filenames? And a stronger statement: may I assume that `glob (3)`, in this case that only one file matches and my pattern uses a prefix, should be as fast as `fstat (3)`?

Research:

- I have read the page http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob and could not find any specific answer to this question.

Comment: Original discussion is from https://github.com/vgough/encfs/issues/7 When creating a filesystem this does matter. I am seeking an authoritative answer that would apply to multiple platforms lest I commit code that works on Linux but is slow on OTHER_OS.

Comment: On a Mac, `glob` uses `readdir`, so it can't possibly be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On *NIX systems, there is only one kernel interface to access the directory content: `readdir()`. On kernel level, *NIX systems don't support any kind of glob or pattern or even prefix matches. Only dumb linear listing of the directory content is supported.

The `glob()` (or similarly `wordexp()`) is a library function which is implemented using the `readdir()` library function. On top of that, it also has to perform the matching using the glob expressions. It can't be faster than hand-coded `readdir()` loop.

P.S. Going level lower, on level of the file-systems: the directory entries on disk generally are not sorted. Thus optimization of the partial file name look-up is not possible. (Additionally, most file systems are oblivious to the charset used to encode the file names.)

Comment: Thank you. Oh wow, I can't even assume `fopen()` is O(1) if files are not sorted!

Comment: Full name look-ups are optimized, typically by hashing. (But it is really more complicated than that, since small/medium/large directories are optimized differently.) Don't forget that the file name and the file are two different things: a file can have multiple names.